How to view HTML in a browser with formatting?

I am an absolute beginner in HTML. I need this HTML page to show formatting in my browser. I just have the file stored on my local drive. Do I need to upload the file to the server for it to be viewed as HTML or can I view locally? As you can see in the screenshot it currently shows the same HTML code. What am I doing wrong? I tried search but I wasn't able to find a solution. Not sure if I am using incorrect wording.

How does the source of the page look like (Press Ctrl+U in the browser window)?

What are you using to edit the HTML? It appears as though whatever you're using is wrapping and escaping what you've typed.

Write your HTML using a programmers' text editor (such as Visual Studio Code, which is free). You appear to have used a Word Processor which has created an HTML representation of what you've typed (i.e. a webpage to display some HTML source code).

This question is similar to: Page shows code not rendering. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

please follow this steps :
first of all => use an other browser and open that html file with the new browser
if Nothing cahnge then => create a new document and save it as html before write down any word, then you caan write your html code and open it  with different browser
